# Ignoring binary files in Maven webapp resource filtering

Tags: maven, web-applications, resources, filtering

Using Maven I need a property replacement of `${project.version}` in an HTML file, so I add this to my POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <webResource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </webResource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But now Maven corrupts some of my font-related files, e.g. `MaterialIcons-Regular.woff`.

Rather than excluding a path glob (which I assume would mean I would need to re-include it in a separate section without filtering), is there any way just to [mark some file extensions as binary](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html) as you can with the `maven-resources-plugin` and `<nonFilteredFileExtension>`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just as it is for `maven-resources-pluging`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <webResource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </webResource>
                </webResources>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>eot</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

(I should have RTM for [`maven-war-plugin` `war:war`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html).)